# WP8 Solution error after opening on new system

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-8, visual-studio-2013

I've been developing a Windows Phone 8 application on my Windows 8.1 system with Visual Studio 2013 Professional. I've bought a new computer, and installed VS 2013 Express for Windows on it, and tried to open the project's solution, but I get a load failed error, with the following output message:

*C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Click4Skill Angol\Click4Skill Angol\Click4Skill Angol.csproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Expression\Blend\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WindowsPhone.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Click4Skill Angol\Click4Skill Angol\Click4Skill Angol.csproj*

I've checked, Blend is installed on the System, but I've also downloaded the Blend SDK and installed it, but it still doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: if you remove that target from the csproj file, does it load OK?

Comment: Does Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Expression\Blend\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WindowsPhone.targets" exists??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You Should try this :

You'll need to install [Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff630878%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

You cannot get the same Visual Studio integration and templates without specifically installing the phone support when installing a full edition of Visual Studio 2013.

Note that Windows Phone 8 development tools require Windows 8 or higher as Hyper-V is required for the Windows Phone 8 emulator.

There is an add-in available to extend existing installations, but it won't work for the 2013 Express edition.

You can also [install the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471) , but you'll need to use Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone for development. You'll not be able to use Visual Studio 2013.